# Tinyint as byte nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate, byte

I have a table with a tinyint column in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, which maps to a byte property in my POCO.

The problem is whenever I run a query with a where clause on the tinyint column using NHibernate, it results in the following sql...

```
and cast(table0_.TinyIntColumn as INT)=@p1
```

I just want to know how to get rid of this behaviour, because although the query still works its annoying and unnecessary, so anyone know of any solutions or come across this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use byte or [change the query a bit](http://blog.hompus.nl/2013/01/21/filtering-on-a-tinyint-with-entity-framework/)

Comment: I've no choice in the SQL data type I'm afraid, and I tried using a list as suggested in that article but that just results in..(table0_.TinyIntColumn in (@p1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the LINQ provider.

Of the following queries:

```
session.CreateQuery("from Foo where TinyIntColumn = :b").SetParameter("b", 1)
session.QueryOver<Foo>().Where(x => x.TinyIntColumn == 1)
session.Query<Foo>().Where(x => x.TinyIntColumn == 1)
```

...Only the last one results in the behavior you are experiencing.

Please open an issue at https://nhibernate.jira.com/